# can an nonzero IC sheaf have zero hypercohomology?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Can someone tell me which of the following are true?  Let $X$ be a reasonable space.

Suppose $F$ is a complex whose cohomology groups are constructible sheaves, at least one of which is nontrivial.

> Can $\mathbb{H}(X, F) = 0$?

If so, can it still happen assuming $F$ is really just

(1) a constructible sheaf 
(2) a local system 
(3) a perverse sheaf 
(4) an intersection cohomology complex ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  Consider any local system (**EDIT:** of rank 1) over a characteristic 0 field on $\mathbb{C}^*$ with non-trivial monodromy.  This satisfies all of (1), (2), (3) and (4). There are lots of ways to check that this has trivial cohomology; for example, if the monodromy has finite order, it's a summand of the pushforward from the constant sheaf, which has the same cohomology as the constant sheaf.  If you want a projective example, an elliptic curve works.

Comment: More generally one can take any $X$ and a proper and generically finite map $f : X -> X$. Then $\mathbb{H}(f_*\mathbb{Q}_X) = H^*(X)$ and so every summand of $f_*\mathbb{Q}_X$ except for $\mathbb{Q}_X$ (an IC by the decomposition theorem) has vanishing cohomology.

Comment: @Ben: When you say "non-trivial monodromy" I guess you mean invariants = coinvariants = 0. Of course local systems with unipotent monodromy on $\mathbb{C}^*$ have cohomology.

Comment: yes, I should have said "no trivial composition factors."  Since we were just looking for one example, I can also just assume rank 1.